# Server accept socket but after that the socket cannot receive anything

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I've encountered a very strange problem (since this always worked before) when building a client-server chat program.

The serversocket accepts without any problem the incoming connection of the client, but when I try to read from the socket's inputstream the whole method blocks and only releases when I close the client's socket.

I've even tried it with the sample code on docs.oracle.com, but the problem remains.

Can anybody point me out the error I'm obviously not seeing?

Server code:

```
public class Server {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Creating server socket");

    ServerSocket internetSocket = new ServerSocket(60000);
    if(!internetSocket.isClosed()) {

        while(true) {
            Socket s = internetSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("accepted socket!");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 60000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Start2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        outStream.println("test");
        System.out.println("Sending the message \"test\"");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Start2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    s.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a true as the 2nd parameter when creating the printwriter [printwriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer,%20boolean%29)

```
new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
```

It will make it flush automatically.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't accept both answers ;-) I just saw the extra constructor argument in PrintWriter too. I guess I was too fast in writing my code. Anywayz also thank you for point it out!

Answer (score 0):

the method `readLine()` is waiting for \n character to appear in the stream (the method blocks until it sees end line delimeter).

Try sending `"test\\n"` from the client and see what happens.

And remember to `flush()` the output stream on the client side

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but nothing different is happening.

Comment: and make sure you flush() the things to the outputStream

Comment: AHA! Somehow adding the flush() did the trick! Any idea why it doesn't flush automatically?  I guess the printwriter initialization?

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure why should it flush() automatically :)